# Running jobs in background in R

Tags: r

I am working with a 250 by 250 matrix. However, it takes loads and loads of time to compute this. It takes like an hour at least.

Is it possible that I can store this matrix in memory in R, such that everytime I open up R, it is already there.

Ideally, I would like to know if it is possible to run a job on background in R , so that I dont have to wait an hour to get the matrix out and be able to play around with it.

Comment: Or checkout the idea of workspaces in R.

Comment: Sorry,, can you be more explicit, what is taking an hour ??? 250x250 matrix is nothing I am working everyday with 3,000,000x20 tables. There is no pb to load a 250x250 on startup, should be instantaneous

Comment: @statquant, the size of the matrix is irrelevant. What is important is how long it takes to compute each value in it...

Comment: @flodel, so why mention its size then? The OP mention to "store this matrix in memory" it all what he wants is store it is just a trivial `write.csv` once the matrix is there and `read.csv` at each startup, but he mentions he wants a background job... this is totally unclear

Comment: Knowing that the matrix is small makes writing/reading to/from a file a very viable solution, so I think it is a good thing he mentioned the size...

Comment: You might get better feedback by posting your problem and code and asking for ways to optimise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would help is to output it to a file when you have computed it and then parse that file everytime you open R. Write yourself a computeMatrix() function or script to produce a file with the matrix stored in a sensible format. Also write yourself a loadMatrix() function or script to read in that file and load the matrix into memory for use, then call or run loadMatrix everytime you start R and want to use the matrix.

In terms of running an R job in the background, you can run an R script from the command line with the syntax "R CMD BATCH scriptName" with scriptName replaced by the name of your script.

Comment: Can you give me some example code please ? Because I understand what you mean, but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: The code would depend on the form of your matrix. If it's just a matrix of numbers I, personally, would output to a csv format and then use the read.csv() function to load it back in. What is each element in the matrix?

Comment: `writeMatrix <- function(dat, file) write.csv(dat, file)`;

`readMatrix  <- function(file) data.matrix(read.csv(file, row.names = 1))`

Comment: To clarify, "dat" is the desired matrix, right? Or do I have to convert it to a data frame first before writing it to a file ?

Comment: Yes it is. http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/datasets/R/html/base/html/write.table.html for extra options you may or may not want.

Answer (score 6):

1) You can save the workspace of R when closing R. Usually R asks "Save workspace image?" when you are closing it. If you will answer "Yes" it will save the workspace in a file named ".Rdata" and will load it when staring a new R instance.

2) The better option (more safe) is to save the matrix explicitly. There are several options how it can be done. One of the options is to save it as Rdata file:

```
save(m, file = "matrix.Rdata")
```

where `m` is your matrix.

You can load the matrix at any time with

```
load("matrix.Rdata")
```

if you are on the same working directory.

3) There is not such option as background computing for R. But you can open several R instances. Do computation in one instance, and do something else on other instance.

Answer (score -1):

It might be better to use the ff package and save the matrix as an ff object.  This means that the actual matrix will be saved on the disk in an efficient manner, then when you start a new R session you can point to that same file without loading the entire matrix into memory.  When you need part of the matrix, only the part you need will be loaded so it will be much quicker.  Even if you need the entire matrix loaded into memory it should load faster than reading a text file.

Comment: The matrix is tiny in this case 250*250. I do not see a reason to use `ff`.

Comment: @djhurio, I agree that for the stated case 250x250 is small and the other methods mentioned will work fine, but what if the original poster, or another reader scales up to a really large matrix?  The ff solution will scale better.

Comment: Yes, but anyway it is out of scope of the question.

Comment: I also frequently use this method, together with the parallel functionality from package parallel. As when you do this, copying the data to the parallel workers only copies the virtual part of the ff object - which is a lot faster than copying all data passed on to a parallel function.