# R - Is it possible to run two (or more) consoles using the SAME environment simultaneously?

Tags: r, memory, parallel-processing, data-science

And if so, how?

I use RStudio. I know I can fork a project in order to perform calculations over two **copies** of the same environment (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137842/run-multiple-r-scripts-simultaneously)). Although, it doesn't fit my needs because the environment I'm currently using is very big, and I don't have enough RAM for duplicating it.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is some way in which I can open two (or more) consoles using the **same** one (in particular, I would be particularly interested on not having to replicate the very big data frames).

Is there a way in which I can use RStudio this way, or is there any other IDE or tool which supports it?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

I will explain what I'm trying to do: I'm developing some machine learning models based on a large dataset.

- I load the dataset into a data frame.
- Then I perform different treatments over the data in order to transform them into ML-friendly data.

I perform these two steps in one R script, and I end up with an environment loaded with a heavy data frame, libraries and some other objects.

- Then I'm using this dataset to feed several ML models: those models are of different classes, and within each class I'm trying several models with different parameters.
- I have one R script for each class of models, and I would like to run and score each class parallel. Each model within each class will run sequentially.

The key here is: I know I can use different projects in order to do this, but that would suppose having to load several times the same environment, and for me that is problematic because it would mean having to load to RAM several times the same big data frame. Therefore I would like to know if there is a way to have several R scripts run in parallel while using the same environment.

- Then I will use another script to rank all the models.

[image: programming flow]

Comment: I can't image what you really want to achieve, but [future](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-1-overview.html) might be helpful: "The purpose of future is to provide a very simple and uniform way of evaluating R expressions asynchronously"

Comment: Hi PoGibas, thank you for your answer. Nevertheless, from what I'm reading I'm afraid future is not what I need. I will try to clarify my need in the original question.